# how to get data from API to Angular Mat editable table using Form builder?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, form-control

This is what I tried and working fine with hardcoded datasource. but throwing error like "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'foreach' of undefined" & "ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'users -> 0'" when getting data from api.

---

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.empService.getEmployees().subscribe((res: any[]) => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res);
    });
    this.tableForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      users: this.formBuilder.array([]),
    });
    console.log(this.dataSource);
    this.setUsersForm();
    this.tableForm.get("users").valueChanges.subscribe((users) => {
      console.log("users", users);
    });
  }
  
  private setUsersForm() {
    const userCtrl = this.tableForm.get("users") as FormArray;
    console.log(this.dataSource);
    this.dataSource.foreach((user) => {
      console.log(user);
      userCtrl.push(this.setUsersFormArray(user));
    });
  }

  private setUsersFormArray(user) {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      employee_name: [user.employee_name],
      location: [user.location],
    });
  }
```

---

```
<form [formGroup]="tableForm">
  <mat-table formArrayName="users" [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="EmployeeName">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell
        *matCellDef="let row let rowIndex = index"
        [formGroupName]="rowIndex"
      >
        <input type="text" size="2" formControlName="employee_name" />
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Location">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Location </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell
        *matCellDef="let row let rowIndex = index"
        [formGroupName]="rowIndex"
      >
        <input type="text" size="7" formControlName="location" />
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Header and Row Declarations -->
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</form>
```

Comment: Since API calls are asynchronus you need to move dynamic form creation inside subscribe.

Comment: sorry I didn't get you. you mean the form builder group should be inside the subscribe?

Comment: move  this.setUsersForm(); inside subscribe.

Comment: yeah I tried that too..but error still persists. The data source is getting undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you needn't has two separates data: dataSource and the FormArray and use valuesChange. You can use the FormArray.controls as dataSource of a mat-table.

As always you work with a From array, create a getter of the FormArray

```
get formArray()
{
    return this.tableForm.get('users') as FormArray
}
```

In ngOnInit, in subscribe, create the FormGroup

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.empService.getEmployees().subscribe((res: any[]) => {
      this.tableForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        users: this.formBuilder.array(res.map(x => this.setUsersFormArray(x)))
      });
    });
}
```

See how we transform the response (res) -an array of objects- in an array of FormGroups using map.

The .html like your code -else the data source-

```
<form [formGroup]="tableForm">
<mat-table formArrayName="users" [dataSource]="formArray.controls">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="EmployeeName">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row let rowIndex = index"  
        [formGroupName]="rowIndex"> 
      <input type="text" size="2" formControlName="employee_name"> 
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>


  <ng-container matColumnDef="Location">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Location  </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row let rowIndex = index"  
      [formGroupName]="rowIndex"> 
      <input type="text" size="7" formControlName="location">
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>


  <!-- Header and Row Declarations -->
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
</form>
```

Really, if you only want to manage a Form array, you needn't create a FormGroup, you can work directly with the formArray

```
tableFormArray:FormArray
ngOnInit() {
    this.empService.getEmployees().subscribe((res: any[]) => {
        this.tableFormArray=this.formBuilder.array(res.map(x => this.setUsersFormArray(x)))
    });
}

<form [formGroup]="tableFormArray">
<mat-table  [dataSource]="tableFormArray.controls">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="EmployeeName">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row let rowIndex = index"  
        [formGroupName]="rowIndex"> 
      <input type="text" size="2" formControlName="employee_name"> 
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>


  <ng-container matColumnDef="Location">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Location  </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row let rowIndex = index"  
      [formGroupName]="rowIndex"> 
      <input type="text" size="7" formControlName="location">
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>


  <!-- Header and Row Declarations -->
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
</form>
```

You can see the two aproach in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ye678m-wsbrzs?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts) (in the stackblitz I return an observable in the own component, change the this.getEmployes by your this.empService.getEmployes)

**Updated** if we want filter the columns using a select in header we can take this aproach (I'm not prety sure if it's the best aproach, perhafps using filter or filtered options). The idea is that the datasource in this case was an array of number with the index of the "selected" elements in a formArray. For this

```
//after create the form array:
this.rowsSelects=this.formArray.controls.map((x,index)=>index)

/* a function to "filter"
   see that we map each formGroup of the formArray in an object with `{index:#,select:true or false}`
  after filter to get only "select", and map to get an array of numbers
*/

selectName(name: string) {
    if (name) {
      this.rowsSelects = this.formArray.controls
        .map((x, index) => ({
          index: index,
          select: x.value.employee_name == name
        }))
        .filter(x => x.select)
        .map(x => x.index);
    } else {
      this.rowsSelects = this.formArray.controls.map((x, index) => index);
    }
  }
```

As dataSource we are going to use `rowsSelects` and to mannage the formArray we use some like

```
   <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row let rowIndex = index"  
      [formGroup]="formArray.at(row)">
      <input type="text" size="2" formControlName="employee_name"> 
    </mat-cell>
```

[a quick stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ye678m-m7rhpi?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts)

Comment: Thank you so much. this is a great answer. I like the way of using FormArray without a FormGroup. But if I do PUT operation then I need  FormGroup right?.

Comment: I understand a PUT operation as an operation that make over an unique element, (and you can send to the API,  e.g. tableFormArray.at(0).value) but you can has an API that received an Array, then check for each element if yet exist or not to make an update or an insert in your dbs (in this case is a POST)

Comment: yeah cool..once again thanks for the answers and multiple aproaches to do.

Comment: @Manmadh, I'm not prety sure, I'm in hurry, but I updated the answer an put a stackblitz that I hope help you

Comment: your answer helped me alot. Thanks for that. but can't we use the same previous tableFormArray as dataSource instead rowsSelects because there might be a problem when saving the edits.

Comment: ::glups:: I used the code of the formGroup. It's only change `formArray` by `tableFormArray`, see this forked stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ye678m-ux9pc7?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts